# I want to make a C++ program that moves files

Tags: c++, windows

I am a fairly new C++ programmer and I am trying to set up a program that moves 2 files into a different location. How do I do this?

Comment: What Operating System?

Comment: Open 1st file for reading, open 2nd file for writing, copy its contents from 1st to the 2nd, close the 2nd. If closing is successful delete the 1st one. If deletion of the 1st fails, delete the 2nd and report an error.

Comment: I'd recommend using Boost.Filesystem considering it's going to become a TS very soon. To my knowledge, Visual Studio supports `<filesystem>` already.

Answer (score 3):

Under Windows, there is an API just for that purpose, the [MoveFileEx()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365240%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

To use it, start with:

```
#include <windows.h>
```

And then you can simply do something like this:

```
BOOL result = MoveFileEx("C:\\dir\\myfile.txt", "D:\\another\\directory\\output.txt", MOVEFILE_COPY_ALLOWED);
```